# Change File Picker Dialog folder location (avoid latest visited folder)

Tags: finder, catalina, ui, dialog

Whenever a File picker dialog (MacOs Catalina) is being open by a website or in general within the operating system, the UI shows as a default folder the latest used/visited one.

Let's consider this typical workflow:

1. I'm saving a file in Word using the Save button, which brings up a File Picker Dialog and I save my document in let say `~/Desktop/myfolder`
2. After some time (even hours later) a website prompts me for a file Upload, which opens the same File Picker Dialog
3. *Here's the issue:* File Picker Dialog opens - by default- into the latest used folder from the Picker Dialog, so the file Picker UI will show files in `~/Desktop/myfolder`.

This is pretty inconvenient as it can expose privacy files when screen-sharing or when having someone next to me when collaborating at the laptop .

Is it possible to use a Default folder for the file picker that opens up always for example in `~/Desktop` or just `~` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to do anything like this natively.

There is such as [Default Folder X](https://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/) which can remember 'last folder per app' or just always return to a specific location per app, with navigation history & fast click-through to any folder already open. You can set up different default sets depending on workflow.

I've actually had it on every Mac I've ever had since before they added the 'X' to the name, before OS X. I can't even remember how limited the standard filepicker is; I'm reminded only when I use someone else's Mac.

Comment: I didn't know this app. I'm testing it right now, is a bit heavy and too much for my use case, but better than nothing at the moment.
Thanks for your suggestion!